# Exclude from MYSQL query when using syntax with JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

I have query

```
SELECT table1.name, table2.wage, table3.bonus table5.shift
FROM table1
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.userid = table2.userid
    INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.userid = table3.userid
    LEFT JOIN table5 ON table1.userid = table5.userid;
```

i need to also look in table "vacation" and exclude them from above query.

```
"vacation.userid" = "table1.userid"
```

like

```
INNER JOIN vacation ON table1.userid != vacation.userid
```

but for some reason this still shows them in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try including the vacation table in as a LEFT JOIN and then add a WHERE clause of getting records where the vacation join failed.

```
SELECT table1.name, table2.wage, table2.bonus table3.shift, table4.vacation
   FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.userid = table2.userid
INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.userid = table3.userid
INNER JOIN table4 ON table4.userid = table4.userid 
LEFT JOIN table5 ON table1.name = table5.position
LEFT JOIN vacation on vacation.userid = table1.userid
WHERE vacation.userid IS NULL;
```

Comment: Note that this will only work if userid is `UNIQUE` in vacation. If people can have more than one vacation record you will get duplicates in your query. See the `NOT EXISTS` version I posted for an alternative.

Comment: I'm a little confused -- this helps by answering the question but you still need a different way to solve the problem?  Is this homework or something?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table1.name, table2.wage, table2.bonus table3.shift
FROM table1
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.userid = table2.userid
    INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.userid = table3.userid
    LEFT JOIN table5 ON table1.name = table5.position
    LEFT JOIN vacation ON vacation.userid = table1.userid
WHERE
    vacation.userid IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table1.name, table2.wage, table3.bonus table5.shift
FROM table1
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.userid = table2.userid
    INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.userid = table3.userid
    LEFT JOIN table5 ON table1.userid = table5.userid;
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM vacation WHERE vacation.userid = table1.userid)
```